# Using session_start with Laravel OR using Laravel sessions across php files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using a Laravel app, and on one of my custom pages I have the following:

index1.php:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../vanguard/extra/auth.php';
$request->session()->forget('token1');
$request->session()->put('token1', $generate_token1);

$request->session()->keep(['token1']);

redirectTo('index2.php');
```

index2.php:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../vanguard/extra/auth.php';
$token1 = $request->session()->get('token1');

echo $token1;
```

It seem's the session isn't being saved across the pages. If I use all the code on one file it works. Any ideas?

I am using this because I can't seem to use `session_start();` with Laravel.

Comment: why you want to use it without controller?

Comment: Because I'm unsure how to.

Comment: Remove `$request` and use only `session()`

Comment: Still does not work. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

Rather making a custom page make a **class** 
define a class with a **namespace**
and **use** it in any of your pages inside any page like below.
Here are my steps :

The content for app/library/myFunctions.php is below :

```
<?php namespace App\library {
    class myFunctions {
        public function is_ok() {
            return 'myFunction is OK';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

At resources/views/test.blade.php , I added :

```
<?php
  $FmyFunctions1 = new myFunctions;
  $is_ok = ($FmyFunctions1->is_ok());
?>
```

Then at composer.json within "autoload": I added :

```
"files": [
    "app/library/myFunctions.php"
],
```

And within app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php at public index() I add :

return view('test');

Comment: I don't quite understand Laravel. Is there any way I can use a custom page?

Comment: that's why answered it so u can imitate each step and accomplish what u want.